# Jetpack Compose Button goes above keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I have some content and a TextField, and a button on the bottom of the screen.
When I tap on the TextField, the keyboard covers my button, but obviously I want the button to go above the keyboard.
How can I do that?

I already added this line to my MainActivity, before setContent():

```
    window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

My Scaffold:

```
  Scaffold { padding ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp)
                .padding(top = 40.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
        ) {
            Column {
                Text("My content")
                Text("My content")
                Text("My content")

                TextField(
                    value = text,
                    onValueChange = { text = it },
                )
            }


            Box(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            ) {
                Button(content = { Text("BTN") }, onClick = {})
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you are add window.setSoftInputMode...

Comment: I doesn't matter if I add it or not, it's not working either way.

Comment: Maybe the issue is not related with the snippet. I tried it and it works fine. Maybe you should start with an empty project and go step by step to see what's causing this issue

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`. You're cured!

Comment: Software version is not required. Remove it off the codebase.

Comment: It's not working, my button is still covered by the keyboard.

Comment: To be clear: if you add it to the activity, like MainActivity, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imePadding()` from modifier

For example:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.imePadding()) {
  // Your rest of code, include the button
}
```